# How to write a SQL statement which gets results via a relationship table? (many to many)

Tags: sql, many-to-many, relational

I have 3 tables (archive has many sections, section (may) belong to many archives):

- `archive`

  - `id PK`
  - `description`
- `archive_to_section`

  - `archive_id PK FK`
  - `section_id PK FK`
- `section`

  - `id PK`
  - `description`

What would the SQL look like to list all the sections that belong a certain archive id?

I am just learning SQL. From what I've read it sounds like I would need a join, or union? FYI I'm using postgres.

---

**[Edit]** This is the answer from gdean2323 written without aliases:

```
SELECT section.* 
FROM section 
INNER JOIN archive_to_section 
ON section.id = archive_to_section.section_id 
WHERE archive_to_section.archive_id = $this_archive_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM section s INNER JOIN archive_to_section ats ON s.id = ats.section_id 
WHERE ats.archive_id = 1
```

Comment: is it necessary to write with the abbreviations? it might be easier to follow for a beginner. thanks

Comment: It is not required to use abbreviations (alias's) many people use them. I prefer not to. See the discussion on the pros/cons of alias's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198196/when-to-use-sql-table-alias

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT s.*
FROM archive_to_section ats
  INNER JOIN section s ON s.id=ats.section_id
WHERE ats.archive_id= @archiveID
```

Comment: Exactly.  The important thing to realize is that the archive table don't figure into this.

Comment: I think you mean INNER JOIN section s ON s.id=ats.section_id

Comment: what do the * and @ symbols mean?

Comment: * means all the fields for that table, @archiveID is a parameter, you can replace it with the archive_id of your choice, if you like.