# Is this an SQL alias or something else?

Tags: sql, alias

In the following code excerpt, I'm wondering what the "p" and "p1" are.
My best guess is that they are aliases, but I can find no alias syntax (ex: people AS p) used in the rest of the code.

```
$query ="SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->postmeta p1
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This isn't sql, and the code isn't even compilable (no closing '"'). What language are you using, and what SQL server?

I assume that the language is PHP. In SQL, you can omit the 'AS' keyword in table names, so, writing `SELECT X.* FROM Table X` is the same, as `SELECT X.* FROM Table AS X`.

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed aliases, this is where they're defined. That's valid SQL syntax, at least in oracle.

The "posts" table is referenced afterwards as "p", and you can see that in the "p.*" part.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198196/when-to-use-sql-table-alias).

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you do not have to use the syntax as to define an alias.  Here is a good StackOverflow link that has been answered : [Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981938/what-is-your-preferred-syntax-for-sql-aliases)