# Get information from a joined table AND a table that isn't joined

Tags: sql

This is the example I am working off of

```
SELECT   *
FROM     table1,
         table2
WHERE    table1.id = table2.id
```

However, my "table1" needs to be a joined table (lets say from tables "tableA, tableB")

I am not sure how to use two tables when one of them is a joined table.  Also, I am not sure how to alias a table that is joined (rename the joined table of tableA/tableB to table1).

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by joined table? do you mean this is a view?

Comment: So essentially what I need is to get information from three tables: table1, tableA and tableB.  I was able to do a join on tableA and tableB to make table2.  However, I now need to gather information from table1 and table2(tableA/tableB combined) but they do not share any key value.  How would I do this?

Comment: if they dont share any key value, then you propably shouldnt be joining them coz you can be sure that your data is valid. If you want to have every record in `table2` be combined with every record in `table1` then you need to do a `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: So explain in business terms how the relation in table1 is related to that in tableA/B

Comment: I understand that it normally isn't logical to do this.  In the future these tables will share a key value.  However, to progress on what I am working on now, I just need to see all the data from table1 and table2(tableA/tableB combined).  I was able to do this using the CROSS JOIN.  Thank you Jafar.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are using is implicit. The ANSI standard syntax uses `JOIN`:

```
SELECT columnList
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b
  ON b.id = a.id
```

The letters following the table names are aliases. Depending on the platform, the rules and proper markup may vary.

**Further reading**

- [Explicit vs. implicit syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)
- [When to use a table alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198196/when-to-use-sql-table-alias)

Comment: nice hint about the implicit vs explicit join syntax, but I am not convinced if this is what the OP actually asked...

Comment: @luksch I agree it's unclear. I did the best with my interpretation and voted to close it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about how to incorporate your joined tables query into this one then you need to include it as a subquery then you would alias that subquery with a name (i.e. table1), here is how it would look like:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     
     (
       SELECT *
         FROM tableA ta, 
             tableB tb
        WHERE ta.?? = tb.??
     ) table1, <-- table1 here is an alias
         table2
WHERE    table1.id = table2.id
```

Here is more info about [Subqueries and joins](http://www.learn-sql-tutorial.com/SubqueriesJoinsandUnions.cfm)