# Return fields from query and subquery

Tags: sql, db2

I'd like join 2 tables but without a INNER JOIN but with nested query.

I have 2 tables :

- TableA : AField1, AField2, AField3, AField4
- TableB : BField1, BField2, BField3

The link between table are AField1 and BField1.

```
SELECT AField1, AField2, AField3
 FROM TableA
 WHERE AField1 IN (
    SELECT BField1 FROM TableB
    WHERE BField3 like 'E11%'
    );
```

I'd like in the result AField1, AField2, AField3, AField4 **and** BField2, BField3

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: So what you want is: You have table1 and table2 and you are trying to get data of table2 without selecting from table2? Why do you want to achieve this without an INNER JOIN?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve with some sample data?

Comment: It's clear, in the result I need some field from TableA and TableB. Why not INNER JOIN, I have performance trouble and I'd like test another way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're trying to achieve--obviously, this solution is contingent on the join integrity. So you'll have to makes sure the PK match to ensure you're not getting an improper join.

```
SELECT a.AField1,
  a.AField2,
  a.AField3,
  bb.BField2,
  bb.BField3
FROM TableA a
WHERE EXISTS
  (SELECT 'X'
  FROM TableB b
  WHERE b.BField3 LIKE 'E11%'
  AND a.AField1 = b.BField1
  )
  (SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE BField3 LIKE 'E11%'
  ) bb
AND a.AField1 = bb.BField1
```

In SQL you can alias the tables--read more about it here:[When to use SQL Table Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198196/when-to-use-sql-table-alias)

Comment: Since the OP is trying to improve the performance, I don't think this will perform better than `JOIN`.

Comment: You could use a correlated subquery; however, you would loose the ability to select b.BField2, b.BField3

Comment: [I told him the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997150/return-fields-from-query-and-subquery#comment-28064609)

Comment: Ok--I updated my code to include a correlated subquery--but then re-select the table to only use tableB to get the column names. I don't have a working DB to test this with, but I'd be tempted to look at the explain plan on these.

Comment: Is that the column name? I took the column name from your example--so there's now way for me to actually validate.

Comment: I get this error : "Toker was not valid. Valid Tokens: FOR SKIP WITH FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT OPTIMIZE".