# Ambiguous Column 'Site_name'

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have inner join two tables and display. I tried the given below code. But it generate on error "Ambiguous Column site_name' "

```
SELECT site_name, Mains_Run_Hrs, DG_Run_Auto_Mode, Battery_Run_Hrs,Solar_Run_hrs 
FROM tbl_runtime_report INNER JOIN tbl_site_details 
ON tbl_runtime_report.Site_ID=tbl_site_details.site_id 
WHEREsite_name=@site_name
```

Comment: use alias name in the columns or tablename.columnname

Comment: @arunbabu you can't use column alias in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `site_name` resides in both tables, you need to specify which version you are querying i.e.

```
WHERE tbl_runtime_report.site_name = @site_name
```

Alternatively, you could use an alias

```
SELECT rt.site_name, ... 
FROM tbl_runtime_report rt ...
WHERE rt.site_name = @site_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  Report.ColumnName,Details.ColumnName
FROM tbl_runtime_report Report
     INNER JOIN tbl_site_details  Details ON Report.Site_ID=Details .site_id 
WHERE Report.site_name=@site_name -- use the relevant alias here
```

See [When to use SQL Table Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198196/when-to-use-sql-table-alias)