# How to fix "ambiguous" where clause in procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an error:

> 1052 - Column 'orderId' in where clause is ambiguous

when trying to do `CALL GetOrderById(2000)`

```
BEGIN
    SELECT
        hsorders.*,
        hslineitem.partNum, hslineitem.price
    FROM
        hsorders
    JOIN hslineitem ON hslineitem.orderId = hsorders.orderId
    WHERE
        orderId = orderId;
END
```

I need to pass an `Id` and join data from two tables that have the same `orderId``.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the complete code.  Where is this programming block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because `orderid` is in both tables.  Hence, the SQL engine does not know which `orderid` the `where` clause refers to.

Let me hypothesize that you have a parameter or variable called `orderid`.

That name conflicts with columns of the same name in the table.  That is why I use prefixes.  For instance, if `orderid` is being passed in as a parameter, I would name it `in_orderid`.  If it were a local variable, I might use `v_orderid`.

Then the code would look like this:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT o.*, li.partNum, li.price
    FROM hsorders o JOIN
         hslineitem li
         ON li.orderId = o.orderId
    WHERE o.orderId = v_orderId;
END;
```

Notice that I also added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thank you! Though I had to change v_orderId to li.orderId if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use alias:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT
        hsorders.*,
        hslineitem.partNum, hslineitem.price
    FROM  hsorders
    JOIN hslineitem ON hslineitem.orderId = hsorders.orderId
    WHERE
        hsorders.orderId = p_orderId;  -- I suggest to rename parameter to avoid 
                                       -- name collision
END
```

Answer (score 1):

ambiguous means use table name or alias name before FIELD

Like `hsorders.orderId` in where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use alias while joining tables. It will be helpful to distinguish the columns if they are in both the tables.

[When to use alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198196/when-to-use-sql-table-alias)

```
BEGIN
SELECT
    HO.*,
    HL.partNum, HL.price
FROM
    hsorders HO
JOIN hslineitem HL 
ON HO.orderId = HL.orderId
END
```

you have already used ON clause to give `HO.orderId = HL.orderId`
so you do not have to use where clause again