# Need to select username from ID in the same query using join. Can't get it working

Tags: sql

I've tried to look, but I can't get a query working.

I have a table called 'replies' and a table called 'users'. 'Replies' had a column called 'used_ID'. I need to get everything from 'replies' and the 'username' of the 'id' 'user_ID'.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT *.replies, users.username
FROM replies * left join users username
    on users.id=replies.added_by
```

I have to make it in one query, but I just don't know how.

Comment: `FROM replies left join users on...`

Comment: *'Replies' had a column called 'used_ID'* but in your code you have *replies.added_by*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT r.*, 
u.username
FROM replies r 
LEFT JOIN users u
on u.id=r.added_by
```

Comment: Thank you! .added_by had to be r.user_id but it works now. But why do I need to have r and u instead of replies and users?

Comment: That's just alias and not required. You can also use table names directly.

Comment: For more details that why we should use table/column alias, you can visit this link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198196/when-to-use-sql-table-alias