# What is the MySQL short reference name called?

Tags: mysql, alias

I've used it for many years, but I don't what it's called.

Example:

```
SELECT u.*, ug.group_name
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN user_group ug ON ug.group_id = u.group_id
```

What is this short reference name called in MySQL?

I've to use it with the [CodeIgniter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeIgniter) query builder, so I don't have to write it with every join function.

Comment: What *short reference name*? Do you mean the `u` and `ug`? Those are [aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198196/when-to-use-sql-table-alias

Comment: Read about the syntax of the [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) statement in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/).

Comment: As you now know, it's called an "alias".  It was a fair question - I don't know why folks are marking you down :(  As Bill Karwin pointed out, other names for this particular alias are "correlation name" and "table alias".

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suppose someone thinks this is a trivial question that is easily answered by reading practically any reference on SQL syntax.

Comment: @BillKarwin I did read briefly but since I forgot it what it's called I think I didn't know where to look.

Comment: If I had forgotten the term, I would have looked in reference documentation for the syntax of a `SELECT` query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Good for you. I know you're an experienced programmer so you know where to look exactly. Not everyone has field experience as yours. Be considerable to others

Comment: I'm not mocking you. I'm suggesting that if you forget a term or a detail of syntax, then it's a logical place to look because the thing you are looking for is a common part of a SELECT statement. It's also a good idea to explore the online docs for the product you're using. I've been using MySQL for many years, and I still look up syntax practically every day. It's easier to use doc for reference than to keep it all in your head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called an **alias** for tables and columns.

Answer (score 1):

When used for a column, it's called an **alias**.

When used for a table, it's officially called a **correlation name** in the ANSI SQL specification.

- Microsoft SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/correlation-names?view=sql-server-2017
- DB2: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_correlationnames.html
- Oracle 12c calls them *table aliases*, but Oracle JavaDB calls them correlation names: https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefcorrelationname.html

But most people call that a "table alias." Even the MySQL manual doesn't call it a correlation name.